# How can I read attributes of a class in an external dll file in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, propertyinfo

I have the following block of code. How can I get all the attribute names from a specific DLL file? Currently, I can get the class names, namespace but I do not know how to get attributes in the class. Thank you,

```
foreach (Type type in myAssambly.GetTypes())
{
    PropertyInfo myPI = type.GetProperty("DefaultModifiers");
    System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes myPA = myPI.Attributes;

    MessageBox.Show(myPA.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Do you mean the names of attribute classes declared within the assembly, or attributes applied to various members?

Comment: Jon, I mean the names of the attributes.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by that. The names of *which* attributes? It would help if you'd show an example of types in an assembly, and the expected output of your code.

Comment: Jon, sorry about not being clear, I am so new to this concept. I uploaded an image that has attributes like Label5 : Label. So Label5 is name of the control and Label is the type of it. I would like to have both. This link has an image of .Net Reflector with my .dll opened. I would like to have the information that you see in the picture http://s7.postimg.org/ydp8xbj9n/assemblyproblem.png

Comment: That looks like you're talking about *properties*, not attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like really you're interested in properties:

```
foreach (Type type in myAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(property.Name + " - " + property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, so it sounds like you *really really* want fields:

```
foreach (Type type in myAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                               BindingFlags.Static |
                                               BindingFlags.Public |
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(field.Name + " - " + field.FieldType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet for the answer, it works but I am not looking for properties. Actually I need to get PDSOptionset, Label etc. These are members of the class.

Comment: @user2599346: Properties *are* members. Perhaps you're looking for fields (which are also members)? If so, the fields in your image aren't named following .NET naming conventions. Again, it's very unclear what you're looking for - and again, it would be *greatly* clarified if you'd include the source code of one of the types you're trying to reflect over in your question, and which bits of it you're looking for. I don't think there's any point in me guessing any further - you *really* need to clarify the question.

Comment: Following is the code of a member I need to get from the .dll. .Net Reflector gave me this code.

<AccessedThroughProperty("BBONNES06")> _
Private _BBONNES06 As PDSTextBox

I need to get something like BBONNES06 - PDSTextBox

Comment: @user2599346: Right, that's a field. So change `GetProperties` to `GetFields` (and specify the relevant binding flags). I'll edit my answer... (But **please** try to be clearer next time. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: my problem is solved. Thank you! I was working on this almost 2 days. May God solve your problems!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compile-time reference to the DLL you can use a type from it to get its assembly, and then use your code to get attributes:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeType));
```

Otherwise you can load it dynamically:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```